# fread in c reads more than instructed

Tags: c, fread

I'm trying to write a program that will add effects to a .wav file.

The program should:

1. Read a .wav file

   - Parse the header
   - Read the data
2. Manipulate the data
3. Create a new .wav file -

   - Write the header
   - Write the new data

I'm stuck on some weird thing with `fread()` function - 
when I'm trying to read 4 Bytes to the char array I've defined (of size 4 Bytes) - I'm getting the word + garbage.

If I try to read 2, or 3 Bytes in the same manner - everything works fine.

I tried printing the content of the array in both cases (when I read 2/3 Bytes v.s. when I read 4 Bytes) with a while loop until '\n' instead of printf("%s") - I got the same result (write string in the first case, string  + garbage in the second case).
Also, whem I write the header back and just COPY the data - the file that is created is NOT the same song! 
It does open - so the header is fine, but the data is garbage.
I'll be very glad to hear some ideas for the possible reasons for this.. I'm really stuck on it, please help me guys!
[The problem -  printscreen of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiE6A.png)

Comment: This is because you need to allocate space for the terminating null character. A c string is always terminated by a null character i.e `\0`. So your buffer needs to have space for 5 characters.

Comment: Even if you haven't been active, you still have been a member for over three years, which should have been plenty of time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and that you read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your questions might be getting negative votes.

Comment: And remember that `.wav` files are *binary* files, they contain no textual data, so you can't really use text functions to print the data.

Comment: Do not describe your code - show your code

Comment: just had a problem and asked for help - no need to school me on how to ask questions - some dude.

Comment: but thanks for your help! It really helped me a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fread` is not intended to read strings. It reads binary data. This means that the data will not be null terminated, nor have any other termination.

`fread` returns the amount of read bytes. After that point, the data will not be initialized, and must be ignored.

If you want to treat the data as string, you must null terminate it yourself with `arr[count]=0`. Make sure that `arr` has a least `count+1` capacity in order to avoid a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reserve 5 bytes for your `fmt_chunk_marker`. That will let you represent a 4-character string as a null-terminated C string. The byte after the last character read should be set to the null character (`'\0'`).